# Understanding 2-way data binding and scope using Leaflet with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I'm used to approaching this problem the React way, with 1-way data binding and state, so I'm having trouble thinking about it with Vue.

I have a map that renders points based on the lat/lng of news stories. When a user changes the value of a select, the points on the map update. When the user clicks on a point, a popup opens with a link to the story. However, I cannot get these two functionalities to work together.

Here's my Vue template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</div>

<select v-model="selectedMonth">
  <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
  <option>January 2018</option>
  <option>December 2017</option>
  <option>November 2017</option>
  <option>October 2017</option>
</select>
<button v-on:click="reset">Reset all</button>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3"
       v-for="(story, index) in displayedStories">
    <img v-bind:src="story.img_src" />
    <br />
    <a v-bind:href="story.url" target="_blank">{{ story.card_title }}</a>
    <p>{{ story.published }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      leafleftMap: null,
      tileLayer: null,
      markers: [],
      allStories: [],
      selectedMonth: null,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getNodes()
    this.initMap()
  },
  computed: {
    displayedStories() {
      const displayedStories = this.selectedMonth
        ? dateFilter(this.selectedMonth, this.allStories)
        : this.allStories

      if (this.leafleftMap) {
        /* remove old markers layer */
        this.leafleftMap.removeLayer(this.markers)

        /* create a new batch of markers */
        const markers = displayedStories.map(story => L.marker(story.coords)
          .bindPopup(mapLink(story))
    )
        const storyMarkers = L.layerGroup(markers)

        /* add current markers to app state and add to map */
        this.markers = storyMarkers
        this.leafleftMap.addLayer(storyMarkers)
        this.changedMonth = this.selectedMonth
      }
      return displayedStories
    },
  },

  methods: {
    getNodes() { /* make api request */ }
    initMap () { /* initialize map with */ }
  },
}
```

The problem is with the line `this.leafleftMap.removeLayer(this.markers)`. When it's there, the markers render and change with the select button, but the popup doesn't work. When I remove that line, the popup works, but the map loses its ability to update when the select changes.

I tried adding a custom directive to the select:

```
<select v-model="selectedMonth" v-updateMonth>
```

in hopes to focus when the JavaScript is enacted:

```
directives: {
  updateMonth: {
    update: function(el, binding, vnode) {
      console.log('select updated')
      vnode.context.leafleftMap.removeLayer(vnode.context.markers)
    }
  }
},
```

but the directive is called whenever anything on the page changed, not just when I update the select.

I'm trying to call a function (to remove the markers) only when the select is changed, but can't seem to get that to work in Vue. It wants to call every function with every update.

Comment: [The directive’s value may or may not have changed, but you can skip unnecessary updates by comparing the binding’s current and old values (see below on hook arguments).](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue with an `@change` and I think I have a better understanding of when to use computed in Vue.

First, I moved a lot of the update logic out of computed:

```
computed: {
  displayedStories() {
    return this.selectedMonth
      ? dateFilter(this.selectedMonth, this.allStories)
      : this.allStories
  },
},
```

so that it's just returning an array. Then I added a listener to the select:

```
<select v-model="selectedMonth" @change="updateStories()">
```

and then created a new method for handling that change:

```
methods {
  updateStories() {
    const markers = displayedStories.map(story => L.marker(story.coords)
      .bindPopup(mapLink(story)))
    const storyMarkers = L.layerGroup(markers)
    this.markers = storyMarkers
    this.leafleftMap.addLayer(storyMarkers)
    this.changedMonth = this.selectedMonth
  },
},
```